# Bootstrap checkbox table

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following bootstrap table.I want to get the selection checkbox but when i will click the button it is not working.
Here is my table:

```
<div class="main">
            <button class="btn btn-default" id="get-selections">
                Get Selections
            </button>


        <table id="table-methods-table" data-toggle="table" data-url="data_out.json" data-height="200">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
                <th data-field="PatName">Name</th>
                <th data-field="KinID">Stars</th>
                <th data-field="Service">Forks</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        </table>
        </div>
```

And here is my javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


    $("#table-methods").next().click(function () {
        $(this).hide();

        var id = 0,
            getRows = function () {
                var rows = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    rows.push({
                        id: PatName,
                        name: 'test' + PatName,
                        price: '$' + PatName
                    });
                    id++;
                }
                return rows;
            },
            // init table use data
            $table = $("#table-methods-table").bootstrapTable({
                data: getRows()
            });
        $("#get-selections").click(function () {

            alert("Selected values: " + JSON.stringify($table.bootstrapTable("getSelections")));
        });
    }); 
});
```

How can get the selection checkbox?

Comment: If I understand, you want get the data-field value ?

Comment: Yes,but only if it is checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something very simple like that :

```
$('#get-selections').click(function() {
    var dataFieldValue = $('#table-methods-table th[data-checkbox="true"]').data('field');
    alert (dataFieldValue)
});
```

With your example the code display "state".

UPDATE 1 :

Check it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bp8z8pha/)

Comment: On the JSFiddle or on your project ?

Answer (score 0):

Put the #get-selections callback just after document ready event like that :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#get-selections').click(function() {
        var dataFieldValue = $('#table-methods-table th[data-checkbox="true"]').data('field');
        alert (dataFieldValue)
    });
    // ... and your script here

});
```

Comment: If you still have an undefined it's because any element has data-checkbox at true value.

Answer (score 0):

Edit this

```
<table id="table-methods-table" data-toggle="table" data-url="data_out.json" data-height="200" data-click-to-select="true">
```